# asp.net Identity user session not expiring using authenticationProperties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to edit a login system using asp.net identity .I need a variable amount of time to expire different users session .I'm trying to expire users from controller and using something like this,

```
var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
             {
                 ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
             };
            authManager.SignIn(authenticationProperties,identity);
```

but when i try something for expiration time like 6 minutes or greater it doesn't expire but works for smaller amount of time like 1-5 minutes.what can be the possible causes ? and 
how can i fix this problem ? 
[i'm not an asp.net programmer so don't know details if anyone can suggest a good tutorial ,it will be very helpful thank you]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

[Click Here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113178/asp-net-identity-expire-session-cookie)

To limit cookie life set ExpireTimeSpan to an hour or second or minute in ConfigureAuth method in Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // other stuff
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    });            
}
```

Comment: this is fixed 1 hour but i need different time out for different user so i need to edit expiration time from controller.can i edit using "authenticationProperties" ??

Comment: try below link.. set the expire time after authentication code..... http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/